# Add location filter to page Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, themes

I'm using wordpress theme `AdForest`. I want to add location filter by regions that changes URL. I have a filter but it doesn't changes page URL so it's bad for SEO. I have a page that changes regions `site.com/ad_country/baranovichi` and page `site.com/ad_category/cats/`. I want to create a page `site.com/ad_category/baranovichi/cats/`. how can I do this?